# Need to format output in csv format

Tags: awk, sed, grep, csv

This is abc.txt file

```
NAME="MARK" StartTime="14:11:26.710583" TotalElapsedTime="0" Pool="10" ThreadsReached="0"
NAME="MARK" StartTime="14:11:26.710583" TotalElapsedTime="0" Pool="10" ThreadsReached="0"
```

Need a output in below format with abc.csv

```
NAME    StartTime   TotalElapsedTime    Pool    ThreadsReached
MARK    14:11:26.710583     0       10      0
MARK    14:11:26.710583     0       10      0
```

Comment: Where are the commas for the csv?

Answer (score 1):

As basic CSV format assumes comma `,` as field separator use the following GNU ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -e '1iNAME,StartTime,TotalElapsedTime,Pool,ThreadsReached' -e 's/[^=]*="\([^"]*\)"/\1,/g; s/,$//g' file
```

The output:

```
NAME,StartTime,TotalElapsedTime,Pool,ThreadsReached
MARK,14:11:26.710583,0,10,0
MARK,14:11:26.710583,0,10,0
```

---

`1i` - inserts *header* line before the first line of the file

`s/[^=]*="\([^"]*\)"/\1,/g` - extracting all attribute values

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS= read -r l; do
   set -f; IFS==; set -- $l; shift; N=$#
   for arg
   do
      set -- ${1+"$@"} "$(expr " $arg" : ' "\(.*\)"')"
   done
   shift "$N"; IFS=,; echo "$*"
done < abc.txt

while IFS= read -r l; do
   set -f; IFS==; set -- $l; shift
   while case ${#} in 1 ) break ;; esac; do
      expr " $1" : ' "\(.*\)"'
      shift
   done | tr \\n ,; expr " $*" : '.*"\(.*\)"'
done < abc.txt

perl -lne '$,=",";
   print /(?:^|\h)\K[^=]*/g if $. == 1;
   print /="([^"]*)"/g;
' abc.txt
```

---

### Explanations

- In the Perl code, from the first line we extract the field names via the regex `/(?:^|\h)\K[^=]*/g` which is read as get me the run of `non=` characters on whose left is seen either a horizontal whitespace `\h` or beginning of line `^`. Then these are printed using the `OFS` `$,` set to a comma.
- For all lines (including the first as well), we extract the field values via the regex `/="([^"]*)"/g` which is to be read as extract the string enclosed with a double quote values (assuming no escaped double quotes) which are adjacent to an equals sign on it's left. The collection of these values are then taken to `stdout` joined with the `OFS`.
- In the case of the `while` loop solution, we first read in the line as is with no word splitting. Then we set the IFS to an `=` and reject the first field. Now all the fields will have the format `"..."...` We then use the `expr` utility to flesh out the value within double quotes and place them on the `$@` array. At the end of the `for` loop we remove the original elements (`$N`) then what remains is what we want. Finally they are joined together by the comma by means of setting IFS to comma and expanding `$*`.